# JavaScript regular expression with * allways matches something

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check that a string consists only of uppercase characters, numbers and underscores.
Therefore I am trying to pattern match using `/[A-Z0-9_]*/`

However, the following code returns `true`:

```
/[A-Z0-9_]*/.test("AJjdada")
```

Is the regex I am using incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean all of this characters should be in the string to test? Does the valid string have a _pattern_ like ABD_DEF_120 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means "*zero or more*". So anything will match as zero times `[A-Z0-9_]` is also considered OK. Use this:

```
/^[A-Z0-9_]+$/.test("AJjdada")
```

`+` means "*one or more*". And `^...$` means beginning and end of the string. This forces all input to match the regex.